# Tensor product of finite $G$-sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products, universal-property

Let $G$ be a finite group. For any finite $G$-set $X$, let 
$$\mathbb{C}\left<X\right> := \left\{\sum_{x \in X} c_x x \mid c_x \in \mathbb{C} \right\}.
$$
Now for finite $G$-sets $Y, Z$, consider the $G$-set $Y \times Z$ by $g(y,z) = (gy, gz)$.

I want to show that there exists a canonical isomorphism

$$\mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right> \tilde{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{C}\left<Y \times Z\right>
$$
of representations of $G$.

Normally we do this by exploiting the universal property of the tensor product: $\mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right>$ together with a $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear map $t : \mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \times \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right> \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right>  $ forms the tensor product of $\mathbb{C}\left<Y\right>$ and $\mathbb{C}\left<Z\right>$. For every Abelian group $A$ and $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear map $b : \mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \times \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right> \longrightarrow A$ there is a unique group homomorphism $\tilde{b} : \mathbb{C}\left<Y\right> \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{C}\left<Z\right> \longrightarrow A$ such that $\tilde{b} \circ t = b$.

Now if we could show that in fact $\mathbb{C}\left< Y\times Z\right>$ is itself a tensor product in this way of $\mathbb{C}\left<Y\right>$ and $\mathbb{C}\left<Z\right>$, we could obtain an inverse group homomorphism of $\tilde{b}$, proving the desired isomorphism. I'm new to this whole kind of reasoning, so it would help me a lot to see how one goes about this.

Comment: I'm all for using universal properties in proofs and all, but here it's just a basic consequence of the fact that $(x\otimes y)_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}$ is a basis for the LHS and $((x,y))_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}$ is a basis for the RHS, and that the $G$-action is the same on both bases. You could write up a universal property-argument, but it would be a bit clouded, because you would for instance define your bilinear map by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$, which would be a bit confusing (you have to parse all the notational abuse yourself)

Comment: I suggest doing this one proof by hand and finding better examples for using a universal property